# How to restrict postfix send limited email with policyd v2?

Tags: postfix, centos5, quota, policyd

I have installed cluebringer-2.0.7 for postfix and enabled below lines in
the main.cf file of postfix. But I could not see any policy working

> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
>   smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031

To check further I enabled logging in policyd and its only shows below logs
and there is no logs getting populated when I send new emails..

> [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE: Process Backgrounded
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CBPOLICYD] NOTICE: Policyd v2 / Cluebringer - v2.0.7
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CBPOLICYD] NOTICE: Initializing system modules.
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CBPOLICYD] NOTICE: System modules initialized.
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CBPOLICYD] NOTICE: Module load started...
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => AccessControl: enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => CheckHelo: enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => CheckSPF: enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => Greylisting: enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => Quotas: enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => Protocol(Postfix): enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE:   => Protocol(Bizanga): enabled
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CBPOLICYD] NOTICE: Module load done.
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE: 2012/06/12-21:18:50 cbp (type Net::Server::PreFork) starting! pid(13949)
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] NOTICE: Binding to TCP port 10031 on host *
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] WARNING: Group Not Defined.  Defaulting to EGID '0 10 6 4 3 2 1 0'
>   [2012/06/12-21:18:50 - 13949] [CORE] WARNING: User Not Defined.  Defaulting to EUID '0'

Do I need to do anymore settings for postfix to listen on policyd???Please
help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all you need to do with Postfix but you need to fill up mysql database used by Policyd.

Copy web files from webui dir to web accessible dir. 
Open the page and set up what you want (quotas, limits etc.).

Do not forget to create some kind of user/pass access control (for example via .htaccess/.htpasswd file...

Comment: sorry i forgot to describ here about webui. i have already configured and connected it with my sql database and it's working fine and i have setup quota values also but it's not workig .

Comment: What do you have inside postfix logs ? I think you should separate values inside smtpd_recipient_restrictions section with , and I don't see them.

Comment: i have the same issue, done everything as described above, no luck yet